# Java Array/ArrayList Replacing Data Already Inside With Data About To Be Added

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, arraylist, data-loss

I have a program that calls a function, **requestAudioBlocks** to request some data. In it, it initialises an array, then calls a request for the data.

```
private ReadAudioData[] receivedAudioMessages;

private int receivedMessageCount;

private boolean requestAudioBlocks(long blocksPerRequest)
{
    receivedAudioMessages = new ReadAudioData[2];

    receivedMessageCount = 0;

    connection.sendRequest();  //Send the command
}
```

When **connection.sendRequest** is run, **connection.sendRequest** calls **saveAudioBlocks**, sending it a variable **download** which is to be put into the array.

```
private ReadAudioData audioDataPacket;

public void sendRequest()
{
    ReadAudioData readAudioData;

    while (int count = 0; count < 2; count++)
    {
        readAudioData = new ReadAudioData();

        //Add the received information into the readAudioData variable

        audioDataPacket = readAudioData;

        saveAudioBlocks(audioDataPacket);
    }
}
```

Every time a new ReadAudioData object is received, saveAudioBlocks is called.

```
public void saveAudioBlocks(ReadAudioData download)
{
    receivedAudioMessages[receivedMessageCount] = download;

    receivedMessageCount++;
}
```

In the running of the program, **saveAudioBlocks** is called twice, which should put two **ReadAudioData** objects into the array **receivedAudioMessages**.

It works the first time, as the correct **ReadAudioData** object goes into **receivedAudioMessages[0]**.

A **ReadAudioData** object has a variable String, which in this case is **"111"**. If you put a break point in **saveAudioBlocks** at the line **receivedMessageCount++**, you can look in the array and it contains the **ReadAudioData** object with String variable **"111"** as it should at location **0**.

However, when **saveAudioBlocks** is called again with a new **ReadAudioData** object, if you look in **receivedAudioMessages** array at location 0, the **ReadAudioData** object is the new **ReadAudioData** object contained in the variable **download** passed to the function, which contains a String variable "122".

It is almost as if I am saving a pointer to the variable **download** in the array and not the actual object as it currently is.

I have tried to use ArrayLists as well, but the same problem occurs.

I have a break point at **saveAudioBlocks** to ensure it is not being called are replacing the data when I am not aware and it is not.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check for value of receivedMessageCount in saveAudioBlocks method, check if it is again set to 0?

Comment: @Ankit it definitely is 0 in the first call and 1 in the second. But weirdly, the value in the Array has changed before the receivedAudioMessages[receivedMessageCount] = download; line is even called the second time!

Comment: post the code "where you are calling `saveAudioBlocks()` method"

Comment: Another hint: Count how many times you call the constructors of 
`RealAudioData` (like `new ReadAudioData()`) in your code. That is the count of objects you really have around. Everything else are just references to these objects. (This is a bit simplified since there are other ways to create new instances, but I would be surprised you have such a case here.)

Comment: @FabianBarney I call a new constructor every time a new ReadAudioData object is received, so twice in total.

Comment: @PippaRoseSmith It does not matter if it is set before or after `receivedAudioMessages[receivedMessageCount] = download;` since you store a **reference** to the object in the array. When you change that object (before or after) it is visible through the reference stored in the array.

Comment: @FabianBarney is there a way to somehow store two separate instances of an object in an array for later? I ultimately want to iterate through the list and do stuff with each object when all the information has been received (baring in mind size could equal 30 - 50).

Comment: You've to create two objects (constructor called twice) and store references to these different objects in the array. Your code storing the references is fine, but you seem to use the same `RealAudioData` object all the time. Your problem is most probably located in the code you did not post where you get your new RealAudioData objects from. It seems to return always a reference to the same instance rather to a new one. Btw: What's the sense of this code snippet: `audioDataPacket = readAudioData;`?

Comment: Please post `ReadAudioData` class with the field you read getting "111" and "222". Want to be sure it is primitive or an immutable object and non-static.

Comment: Thanks so much @FabianBarney I created two different ReadAudioData objects. I was using the same object just overwritten before and now it works fine

Comment: You've two local variables `ReadAudioData readAudioData` in your method - that does not even compile. Please post the "real" code or a SSCCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is almost as if I am saving a pointer to the variable download in the array and not the actual object as it currently is.

This is what happens. You store the *reference* to the object that is *referenced* by the local variable `download`. So if properties of that object change, then the change becomes "visible" in your array too.

Arrays do not store the objects themselves, they store references to objects.

Comment: Oh right. That will be the problem then. Can you suggest a way I can store two different objects in an array without storing the same object twice?

Comment: Thanks. I created two different ReadAudioData objects. I was using the same object just overwritten before.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely because in your calling code (where you call `saveAudioBlocks` you reuse the same `ReadAudioData` variable instead of creating a new one.

In other words, if you do this:

```
ReadAudioData data = new ReadAudioData();
data.setId("111");
receivedAudioMessages[0] = data;

data.setId("222");
receivedAudioMessages[1] = data;
```

Both `receivedAudioMessages[0]` and `receivedAudioMessages[1]` contain a reference to the same data, which now has an id of 222. You would get the same behaviour with an ArrayList.

This is a guess only as you have not provided the code that calls the `saveAudioBlocks` method.

Comment: It is overwritten in the calling code and the saveAudioBlocks function is definitely sent the right ReadAudioData object both times.

Comment: @PippaRoseSmith I suggest you edit your question and post the code that calls saveAudioBlocks.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included it. I have edited it and include the code @assylias

Comment: @PippaRoseSmith The critical part is in `//Request a new ReadAudioData object, stored in readAudioData (code missing)` So it is still not possible to help you much until you show how you create the new RealAudioData object. Also can you confirm that the field you are looking at (111, 222 etc) is not static?

Comment: @PippaRoseSmith The code you have posted looks fine and does not contain anything that could lead to the behaviour you describe. So the problem is probably in what you have not posted I'm afraid. To avoid going in loops for ever, I suggest you post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. If people can reproduce what you get on their machine, it will be much easier for them to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turned out all I needed to do was create a new ReadAudioData object each time instead of overwrite a ReadAudioData object with different data. Thanks again for your time.